# How can I read bmv2 queueing state with P4 language?

Tags: p4-lang

I'm writing a test [P4](http://p4.org/) language in which I prepare to read the queueing state of the software switch bmv2 .There is no relevant content in the P4 program specification.But I found a mail in the mail list which is:

> Hi Wei,
>
> There is no standard way to get a timestamp in P4, as you can see in the spec.
>
> However if you are using the simple_switch bmv2 target, you can still have access to this information. You need to include the following in your P4 program:

```
header_type intrinsic_metadata_t {
    fields {
        ingress_global_timestamp : 48;
    }
}

metadata intrinsic_metadata_t intrinsic_metadata;

header_type queueing_metadata_t {
    fields {
        enq_timestamp: 48;
        enq_qdepth: 16;
        deq_timedelta: 32;
        deq_qdepth: 16;
    }
}

metadata queueing_metadata_t queueing_metadata;
```

> All timestamps are in microseconds
>
> intrinsic_metadata.ingress_global_timestamp is the timestamp when the switch starts processing the packet queueing_metadata.enq_timestamp is the timestamp when the packet is enqueued (between the ingress and egress pipelines)
>   queueing_metadata.deq_timedelta is the time the packet spent in the queue (I believe it is what you are after).
>   It is important to understand that these metadata fields are specific to the simple_switch target, they are not standardized by P4. bmv2 will detect that they are defined in the P4 program and leverage them.
>
> Because bmv2 has a low throughput, I recommend rate-limiting your links to < 100Mbps. You can also use the "set_queue_rate" simple_switch CLI command to rate-limit the bmv2 queue. Please make sure that you compile bmv2 with O2 and without logging (./configure 'CXXFLAGS=-O2' --disable-logging-macros --disable-elogger), otherwise throughput will be really bad.
>
> Best,
>
> Antonin

I add the code mentioned in the mail to test whether it can work:

```
modify_field(ipv4.ttl,10);
add_to_field(ipv4.ttl,queueing_metadata.deq_qdepth);
```

But the result is It don't work,what should I do?Appreciate any help,thk.

Answer (score 3):

I asked the same question at the p4lang repository and the problem solved , thanks for the author's help , as you can see [here](https://github.com/p4lang/behavioral-model/issues/311) .

By the way , the runtime command `set_queue_rate` is `simple_switch` specific .

Comment: Could you share link for simple_switch_CLI please? 
I couldn't find set_queue_rate in runtime_CLI.